# It's possible to use laravel blade templating into css.php?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I want to use php variables into a css file. I found in other questions how to do it, but now I wonder if it's possible to use Laravel methods to do it.

For example obtaining data from the database with Eloquent or use blade templating like:

```
#main{ width:100%; background-color: {{ $bgcolor }}; overflow:hidden }
```

Anyone did something similar?

Comment: You can, but you need a controller to handle a response with the right headers. Like you would normally do with a php file used for generating CSS. You could also consider using LESS or SASS if you want a "dynamic" stylesheet

Comment: Note that this will slow down your site, because for every CSS request you will have to boot up Laravel and even make DB calls. This takes much longer than just returning a file. If you have small parts like the background color that is configurable per db I would just use an inline `<style>` tag for those styles.

Comment: I want to do a small CMS with Laravel, and like in WordPress themes, I want to change some styles from a control panel without typing code. I'm not pretty sure how WordPress handle this, but I think that's something similar.

Comment: @lukasgeiter that's true, but a little bit of cache would ease things a bit